# .val in Jquery is not working after a JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying update a select field after an asynchronous request for a json file, but there is something wrong. Take a look at the code:

```
<script>                
  state = <?= $state ?>; //..var of php that I'll use to set a select field
  idCity = <?= $idCity ?>; //..var of php                
  $.when(getAllStates()).done(function(){ //..using when to execute something only after the function
    $('#state').val(state);  //..set the select field with var state - not working!
  });
</script>
```

I did it using **$.when** because only at the end of the request I'll update the select field, but unfortunately it's not working.... the function ***getAllStates()*** is defined in a js file, it is a json request. If I execute **$('#state').val(state);** in Javascript console, works perfectly. Is there somebody who can help me?

Comment: when you are using this code what error you get in your console.

Comment: I have sometimes seen issues with types. Assuming `$state` is an integer, since if it was a string then it should have been something like `"<?=$state?>";`, you could be having a problem since HTML input fields (e.g., `$('#state')`) are strings. Often best to force everything to string.

Comment: What does `getAllStates()` do? Can you show a sample response?

Comment: I highly recommend making your PHP variables safe for JS via `var state = <?= json_encode($state) ?>;`

Comment: @31piy it' the output, a json file: [{"state_city":"AC"},{"state_city":"AL"},{"state_city":"AM"},{"state_city":"AP"},{"state_city":"BA"},{"state_city":"CE"},{"state_city":"DF"},{"state_city":"ES"},{"state_city":"GO"},{"state_city":"MA"},{"state_city":"MG"},{"state_city":"MS"},{"state_city":"MT"},{"state_city":"PA"},{"state_city":"PB"},{"state_city":"PE"},{"state_city":"PI"},{"state_city":"PR"},{"state_city":"RJ"},{"state_city":"RN"},{"state_city":"RO"},{"state_city":"RR"},{"state_city":"RS"},{"state_city":"SC"},{"state_city":"SE"},{"state_city":"SP"},{"state_city":"TO"}]

Comment: @Phil, thanks for sugestion, but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: @manassehkatz the variable state is a string. Thanks!

Comment: Its a bit confusing. Can you show your complete code? Does `getAllStates()` fills the select box as well?

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments:
`state = <?= $state ?>;`
assigns the string variable $state as plain text. Depending on the value, that may result in a Javascript assignment of a number (e.g., if $state == '7' then the Javascript assignment will be `state = 7;` which will make `state` numeric) or an object that would likely be undefined. In any case, for .val() to work reliably it should be a string. So change it to:
`state = '<?= $state ?>';`
and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: if you put `console.log(state)` right after the .val() statement, what does it show in the console?

Comment: if I put  `console.log(state)` right after the `.val()` I statement, it will show the expected value, a string. I need to wait the complete execution of `getAllStates()` because it will fill a select field with values from a json request. Thus, I can select one of this values using `.val()` statement. Unfortunately it hasn't been working.....